# How to position a Handled Tool Item to the right

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I've an application built on eclipse e4 framework. I want to position a `Handled Tool Item` to the far right end. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two 'Toolbar' entries with a 'Tool Control' between them:
[image]

so something like:

[image]

In the Tags for the Tool Control add the word `stretch` this will make the trim bar manager stretch out the control to use all available space pushing everything after it to the right:
[image]

The class for the control can something simple like:

```
public class SpacerControl
{
  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct(Composite parent)
  {
    Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    body.setLayout(new GridLayout());
  }
}
```

Comment: It did not stretch fully, the SignIn button moved a little bit to the right but not to the right corner

Comment: Sorry, I was forgetting you have to use two Toolbars (one for left and one for right) with the Tool Control between them. See update

Comment: The SignIn button now moved to the far right, but the List and Summary buttons disappeared. List and Summary are the children of ToolBarA, followed by a ToolControl with tag stretch followed by a ToolBarB whose child is the SignIn button

Comment: Do I need to have a class for the ToolControl?

Comment: You get errors logged if you don't have a class for the tool control. Don't know why the left items are not working - check they are still marked as 'visible' and 'to be rendered'

Comment: Thanks, the space class was necessary for the ToolBarA's children to show up.

Comment: is it possible to have a JavaFx button at the Toolbar? I need a button with a background color and currently SWT doesn't support the same on windows.

Comment: You can use JavaFX for everything using e(fx)clipse but you can't mix it with SWT. [Opal widgets](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) does a colored background button.

Comment: If I want to add an OButton to the toolbar, would ToolControl be the best option?

Comment: I think that should be OK.