# Increase the height of the toolbar in an E4 application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I've an E4 application where the toolbar needed a custom colored button. I'm using a ToolControl and creating a [OButton](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/OButton). The problem is the button gets chopped off, Is there a way I can increase the height of the toolbar?

[image: T]

Comment: Is the tool control inside a Toolbar in the Trimbar or is it just in the Trimbar? When it is just in the Trimbar the bar depth is normally adjusted to fit the control.

Comment: Here is the hierarchy, TrimBars>WindowTrim>Toolbar>ToolControl. The TrimBars>WindowTrim>Toolbar is in the application.e4xmi while the ToolControl is in a fragment.e4xmi

Comment: Try adding it directly to the trimbar, tool controls don't have to be in a toolbar.

Comment: Well on the application.e4xmi I've Toolbar-ToolControl-Toolbar. This ToolControl is a child of the 1st Toolbar. I have Toolbar-ToolControl-Toolbar  because I needed a space between 2 buttons, here is a link to the question asked earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484737/how-to-position-a-handled-tool-item-to-the-right/ If I remove the toolbar and add the ToolControl driectly as a child to the Window Trim then the button moves all the way to the right.

Comment: At a guess you are adding the control after the control with the 'stretch' tag, add it before that control (use the 'Position in list' in the model fragment)