# How to position a Handled Tool Item to the right using Model Fragments

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

My question is about a thing [already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484737/how-to-position-a-handled-tool-item-to-the-right) here, but for another context, and that is using the Fragments model instead of the normal way of doing things.

With Fragments, I have to declare a trim contribution and a toolbar contribution separately.

[image: Fragments view]

And I don't see how I'd tag the Tool control as "stretch".

[image: Tool Control editor]

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I have no idea what.

## EDIT:

I have found the "tags" thing, it's in the `Supplementary` bottom tab of the tool control, but it's not working. Do I have to reference the trim contribution somewhere else?

In the example of the other question, there's a `SpacerControl` method. Is that necessary? Doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Comment: The SpacerControl is the class for the Tool Control with 'stretch'  it just occupies the empty space.

Comment: @greg-449 I think I made it work, sorta. There is  the empty space there, but it's like a blocking element. In other words, there's this invisible blob that won't accept a toolbar in its stead. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing - are you trying to drag something to that space?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes. It didn't completely work. It created space, yes, but the thing is not moved completely to the very end. So I tried moving stuff, and now it acts like there's a toolbar there, an invisible one that I can't interact with but takes up space.